# My code compiles, executes, but crashes for certain inputs

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to get the length of longest common subsequence for two strings. It works for most of the inputs but it crashes for the input specified. The code is as follows:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

/* Utility function to get max of 2 integers */
int max(int a, int b)
{
    return (a > b)? a : b;
}

/* Returns length of LCS for X[0..m-1], Y[0..n-1] */
int lcs(string &X, string &Y, int m, int n )
{
    int L[5000 + 1][5000 + 1] = {0};
    int i, j;

    /* Following steps build L[m+1][n+1] in bottom up fashion. Note 
      that L[i][j] contains length of LCS of X[0..i-1] and Y[0..j-1] */
    for (i = 0; i <= m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= n; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0)
                L[i][j] = 0;

            else if (X.at(i - 1) == Y.at(j - 1))
                L[i][j] = L[i - 1][j - 1] + 1;

            else
                L[i][j] = max(L[i - 1][j], L[i][j - 1]);
        }
    }

    /* L[m][n] contains length of LCS for X[0..n-1] and Y[0..m-1] */
    return L[m][n];
}

int main() {
    string A, B;
    cin >> A;
    cin >> B;

    int count1 = lcs(A, B, A.size(), B.size());

    cout << count1;
    return 0;
}
```

And the input strings are as follows:

```
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
```

I tried using c-style strings but yet it was crashing. I also tried dividing it into multiple strings if the input strings are greater than a threshold but it still didn't work. Hope someone finds the bug. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Time to learn more debugging tools: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`, perhaps also `-fsanitize=address`, the `gdb` debugger, [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), `strace`. Details are implementation specific.

Comment: Before I start to count: is any of the 2 strings longer than 5000 characters?

Comment: No, none of them is longer than 5000.

Answer (score 6):

This local declaration:

```
    int L[5000 + 1][5000 + 1] = {0};
```

is allocating 25 million `int`-s, i.e. 4 byte words (so 100 megabytes), on the call stack. Typical [call stacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) have a few megabytes at most on current desktops and laptops, so you'll better use a few kilobytes in each call frame (but YMMV).

You are sure to experience [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow).

You might consider heap-allocated  C++ [standard containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/), e.g. [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (even when you have local container variables on the stack, most of the actual data is heap allocated).

As I commented,  time to learn more debugging tools: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`, perhaps also `-fsanitize=address`, the `gdb` debugger, [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), strace. Details are implementation specific.

And of course, read several good books about C++11 (or C++14): a [Tour of C++](http://stroustrup.com/Tour.html) & [Programming - Principles and Practice using C++](http://stroustrup.com/programming.html)

If you are coding on Linux, [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) is also worth reading.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It worked!! I didn't expect that this could be the issue. Also will look forward to learning the debugging tools you mentioned.